# Cordova camera doesn't rotate the pic to correct orientation on Samsung S3

Tags: android, cordova

```
    var onSuccess = function(imageUri){
        $scope.report.imgUri = imageUri;
    };

    var onError = function(message){
        alert('Failed because: ' + message);
    };

    $scope.capturePhoto = function(){
        navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onError, {
            quality: 40,
            destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            correctOrientation: true,
            saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
            encodingType: navigator.camera.EncodingType.PNG,
            targetWidth: divWidth
        });
    };
```

I am building Cordova 3.5.0 on Samsung S3 with Android 4.3. The `camera.capturePhoto` function always ignore `correctOrientation` set, so the pic did not rotate to correct orientation. But it works fine on HTC Butterfly with Android 4.4. BTW, `encodingType` not work on android either. Any idea?

Comment: I have the same issue using phonegap build to compile, whereas compiling with cordova-cli works fine. Is it the same for you ?

Answer (score 7):

In some cases, setting navigator.camera.EncodingType.JPEG helped.

```
encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
mediaType: Camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
correctOrientation: true
```

Comment: Where do you set it? Do you have a complete example?

Comment: some people said `allowEdit` should be enabled too.